# Twitter account access limit per day

Tags: javascript, twitter

I am using a small javascript code to display the latest 3 tweets from my twitter account in a website.
Every time the page loads, this JS accesses the twitter account to fetch the latest 3 tweets.

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/HANDLE" data-widget-id="12345678912365479525" data-chrome="nofooter" data-tweet-limit="2">Tweets by @HANDLE</a>

<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
```

I have read about the limit on no. of users allowed per day at 250. Is this true ? 
I didn't find anything concrete about this on the net.

I found this 1 link but couldn't make out much of it:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a link to the limits for each type of api call.. Based on a 15 minute rate limit window.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1/limits